# Tab Bar Item oversizing when using free PNG icon

Tags: ios, icons, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I'm currently trying to set the tab bar item (tab image) for my apps. I'm using one of the many PNG CC/Free icons from the site; but when i attempt to set them through storyboard, i'm getting a visual bug where they are oversize.

[image]

I wanted to know why this is happening/how to fix it. I'm downloading them black from thenounproject; but they're not sizing correctly, nor are they the color black. I've placed the PNG in assets and dragged it to the 3x slot, but all it did was make it smaller (the picture shows the smallest; with 1x being quite larger).

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

navigation bar, tool bar, and tab bar icons has fixed sizes as mentioned in Apple documentation.

please check : [Human Interface Guidelines - Custom Icons](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/custom-icons/)

tab bar icon size has to be:

**Recommended:**

75px × 75px (25pt × 25pt @3x)

50px × 50px (25pt × 25pt @2x)

**Maximum:**

144px × 96px (48pt × 32pt @3x)

96px × 64px (48pt × 32pt @2x)